# ld: framework not found Python

Tags: xcode, python-2.7, anaconda

I am trying to install a python module (SPArse Modeling Software) but the install script doesn't seem to be able to find the system's default Python.framework.  This is an almost new (no migration assistant) Mac OS 10.9.5 system with both the default system python and Anaconda installed.  I briefly installed Enthought Canopy but removed it when I decided to go with Anaconda.  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework exists and seems to have all the files you would expect.

In terminal, this is what happens:

```
bash-3.2$ which python
//anaconda/bin/python
bash-3.2$ cd spams-python
bash-3.2$ python setup.py build
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building '_spams_wrap' extension
gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -I//anaconda/include -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I. -Ispams/linalg -Ispams/prox -Ispams/decomp -Ispams/dictLearn -I//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7/ -I//anaconda/include/python2.7 -c spams_wrap.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/spams_wrap.o -DNDEBUG -DUSE_BLAS_LIB -fPIC -fopenmp -m32
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-fopenmp'

#Omitting some irrelevant (I think) warnings#
4 warnings generated.
gcc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L//anaconda/lib -arch x86_64 -arch x86_64 build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/spams_wrap.o -L//anaconda/lib -lstdc++ -lblas -llapack -o build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/_spams_wrap.so -m32 -framework Python
ld: framework not found Python
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

So, my question is, is my diagnosis of the problem correct? How can I tell GCC where Python.framework is?  Is there some environment variable that isn't set correctly?

Comment: Update: commenting out "'-framework', 'Python'" in setup.py allows everything to compile.  I have not tested yet, but if everything runs OK I will post my own answer and close this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Anaconda Python is not a Framework build of Python. If the module expects that it's not going to work. Commenting out commenting out "'-framework', 'Python'" in setup.py sounds like a good start, and if it works, then it probably is the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

Compile it with gcc-5, and I successed.